# Target Unreachable, 'current' returned null - AbstractFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2, jpa-2.0, abstract-factory

I'm trying to access an object inside a managed bean, which implements `AbstractMB`. Any property accessed by a page has error "Unknown property". When I try to insert it in the database,through a commandButton, `PropertyNotFoundException` is thrown.

AbstractMB relevant code:

```
public abstract class AbstractMB<T> implements Serializable {

    private Class<T> type;
    private AbstractDAO<T> typeDAO;

    private T current;
    private List<T> elements = new ArrayList();

    protected T object = this.getCurrent();
    protected List<T> list = this.getElements();

    public abstract void save(ActionEvent actionEvent);

    public AbstractMB() {}

    public AbstractMB(Class<T> type) {
            super();
            this.type = type;
    }

    public T getCurrent() {
            return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(T current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

}
```

Full FonteMB class:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class FonteMB extends AbstractMB<Fonte> {

    public FonteMB() {
        super(Fonte.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(this.object.getCodigo() == null) {
            this.getTypeDAO().add(this.object);
        } else {
            this.getTypeDAO().edit(this.object);
        }
        this.object = new Fonte();
        this.list = null;
    }

}
```

Class Fonte from the model package implements `java.io.Serializable`, all getter and setter, `hashCode` and `equals` methods. And `toString` returning the class name ("Fonte").

Also tried to use a converter, but result was the same.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Check you've got JSF related libraries (jars) in your classpath and also a faces-config.xml file to make it work. I would also try some simpler not DAO related bean till I get it work.

Comment: I have the libraries in classpath and I'm using JSF 2.0, so faces-config.xml is not required.

Comment: faces-config could be required in order to make your annotations be scanned. I just would try to add the simplest faces-config configuration to see if it works.

Comment: Adding faces-config.xml didn't work.